# How to resolve mypy errors for unittests in separate tests direcotry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, mypy

Following is my project structure

```
rolutte
├── doc
├── README.rst
├── src
│   ├── outcome.py
│   └── __pycache__
├── tests
│   ├── context.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── test_outcome.py
└── tox.ini
```

Here are the contents of my `outcome.py`, `tests/context.py` and `tests/test_outcome.py`

```py
# outcome.py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Outcome:
    ...
```

```py
# tests/context.py
import os
import sys


# Adding the project root directory to sys.path
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

import src
```

```py
# tests/test_outcome.py

from .context import src
from src.outcome import Outcome

def test_outcome():
    ...

def test_outcome_win_amount():
    ...
```

Though `pytest` is working fine. But mypy shows the following error for `tests/context.py`

```
tests/context.py:9: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "src"
tests/context.py:9: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

And following for `tests/test_outcome.py`:

```
tests/context.py:9: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "src"
tests/test_outcome.py:6: error: Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "src.outcome"
tests/test_outcome.py:6: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
Found 2 errors in 2 files (checked 1 source file)
```

But I have properly provided type hints in my `src/outcome.py` module while implementing the `Outcome` class for all the methods and attributes. I don't want to install my `src` directory as a site package if that could be the solution.

Please tell me how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running project from **rolutte** folder.
So every import has to be made from that root folder. That mean `from .src.outcome import smth`.

Dot represents **root folder**, every other dot represents **subfolder/file**. This means that you can see first `.` as `.\` and any other as `\` like it is in **Windows**.

EDIT:

From root folder **rolutte** `import` everything in the same way.

Let's say I want to import every file inside **test_outcome.py**, this is how it would look like:

```
from .src.outcome import *
from .tests.context import *
from .tests import * -> based on __init__.py I guess there is a package.
```

If you change all `imports` in each file based on this syntax and then launch script from **rolutte** root folder, it should work.

**NOTE**: If you run script from subfolder such as **tests** folder. The script is unable to see **src** folder because it is in different **tree**. You could use os.path.insert(....). But easier is to just launch the script from **rolutte** folder.

Comment: I couldn't understand very much. But if I run `mypy` from `rolutte/tests` folder I also get the same error. Also, I am using Sublime text and my linter '`SublimeLinter-mypy`' is also marking the import lines as an error.

Comment: Try to `import` all the folder from root folder **rolutte**. Run the script from the root folder **rolutte**.

To Import all the files from **root** inside each file you have to have same approach everywhere. This means you should always start `import` with `.folder.file or another folder`. Lemme edit my post to show you.

Comment: I replaced my `imports` from the lines in your code snippet in `test_outcome.py` file and ran `mypy` from `rolutte` folder. Now it gives two errors. Also `pytest` is unable to run tests. Thanks...

Comment: I mean it's hard to help you if I cannot see what you changed and how. There has to be mistake with `imports`. `imports` are simple if you get a know-how. It was only an **example** of how `imports` works from parent folder.

Comment: I just replaced the first two `import` lines from `test_outcome.py` with first two `import` lines from your code snippet.

Comment: I also just tried a hack, I just added an `__init__.py` file in my src directory and all `mypy` errors were gone. Though I couldn't understand how it happened.

Comment: Some errors are indescribable... I hope it will work fine. We could join forces in afternoon if you could not solve it . But I cannot give it my all right now.